# bitcoin-qt importaddress not working

Tags: importaddress

using bitcoin-qt 0.19.0.1 on mac, I type this in console:
importaddress someaddress "" false
After I hit enter, the output is "null". What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal - importing an address does not produce any output, and you will see `null` in the debug console.

Comment: ok fine, except that nothing gets imported

Comment: If you don't rescan, you won't see any transactions relating to that address - your posted command also seems to be missing the actual address, but I assumed you had redacted that for privacy

Comment: I have a pruned chain, how long will a rescan take ?

Comment: With a pruned chain, you'll only see transactions for the blocks that haven't been pruned yet even after a rescan - there is no way to do a complete history on a pruned node (you will, however, always get an accurate result for the currently spendable balance even with a pruned node) - a full rescan on my nodes tends to take about 40-80 minutes, depending on what else is running. Should be less for a pruned node

Comment: when I try importaddress with rescan=true I get: Rescan is disabled when blocks are pruned (code -4). So it seems "importaddress" never works when in pruned mode